# How close to the critical value to be accsepted?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

What if this number 12.32056265 is so close to the 0.05 critical value which is 12.59. Can it still be a significant value with a positive correlation? Or is it then with the critical value of 0.10 which is 10.64 and a non significant correlation?

Comment: No it can't be. It sounds like you may have some bias in determining the level of significance/p-value.

Comment: Short answer: if a statistic is 12.32 and the 5% critical value is 12.59 and the 10% critical value is 10.64 then your P-value is between 0.10 and 0.05. Longer answer: If you are calculating correlations what precisely is 12.32...? It can't be a correlation. I don't understand what else it might be. I suspect that you are using the word _correlation_ in some non-standard sense. You need to tell us more about what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to reject this null, then there are more subtle and less obvious ways of doing, but we're not going to teach you bad habits here. So, NO is the answer in an inference framework with p-values. It's either greater than a critical value, or not. There's no such a thing as "almost." This applies to the p-values too: you can't evaluate their magnitude beyond saying they're bigger than the significance or not.

Comment: I agree that one should not move their significance thresholds after doing their hypothesis testing, but I think it's a very narrow interpretation of p-values that argues that p=0.05001 and p=0.04999 warrant completely different conclusions about your data. A very small p-value can also be an imprecise proxy for effect size, as larger effects tend to have smaller p-values. It's better to just show the effect size, but reducing a numerical p-value to a dichotomous "significant or not" does throw away meaningful information; p=1e-100 is far better evidence than p=1e-2.

Comment: @NuclearWang It's the other way round. P-values quantify departure from the null hypothesis. It's not a problem in the interpretation of P-values that some want to imply that there is a big difference between P just above and just below any threshold. That is a problem with significance testing. It is like blaming the measurement of height for people being divided into tall and short; on the contrary, measurement of height is informative. (Not enough space to say what else is wrong with P-values....)

Comment: @NuclearWang, yes, the "problem" is with significance testing approach. Within this approach it's either significant or not, there's no shades of grey or colors. If you disagree with this, then use a different approach to inference